# R - Add values (derived by a formula) in a dataframe column based on a condition met by values in a column of another dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, median, data-wrangling

Here is an example dataset:

```
data = data.frame('Cat' = c('A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C'),
                  'Value' = c(1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,3,3))
data
```

[image]

Another dataframe:

```
a = data.frame('Name' = c('A', 'B', 'C', 'D'))
```

**Desired output:**

[image]

**I want to understand how to give reference of another cell within the same row of a dataframe, and perform some function using the value of that cell.**

This **worked** for "In Data":

```
a[,'In Data?'] = ifelse(a$Name %in% unique(data$Cat), "Y", "N")
```

This **failed** for median:

```
b$Median = median(data$Cat[data$Cat == a$Name])

Error message:
Error in Ops.factor(data$Cat, a$Name) : 
  level sets of factors are different
```

This **failed** for count:

```
a$Count = ifelse(a$Name %in% unique(data$Cat), length(data$Cat==a$Name), 0)

Error:
Error in Ops.factor(data$Cat, a$Name) : 
  level sets of factors are different
```

.
.
2nd Dataframe columns :

1. Cat : A B C D
2. count :
3. proportion :
4. median :
5. values > median :
6. f(x) : {count + 10}
7. In Data? :

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's better to frame these operations as merging and summarizing. (Talking in terms of cells and rows seem very Excel-like rather than R-like). The `dplyr` package helps a lot here

```
library(dplyr)
a %>% 
  left_join(data, by=c("Name"="Cat")) %>% 
  group_by(Name) %>% 
  summarize(
    Count=sum(!is.na(Value)),
    Median=median(Value),
    ValuesGtMed=sum(Value>Median),
    f = Count+10,
    InData = if_else(Count>0, "Y","N")
  ) %>% 
  mutate(Proportion=Count/sum(Count))
```

The `left_join` makes sure we get all values in `a` and then we just use different summary functions per the groups defined by `Name`

Output:

```
  Name  Count Median ValuesGtMed     f InData Proportion
  <chr> <int>  <dbl>       <int> <dbl> <chr>       <dbl>
1 A         3      1           0    13 Y             0.3
2 B         2      2           0    12 Y             0.2
3 C         5      3           0    15 Y             0.5
4 D         0     NA          NA    10 N             0
```

Comment: I've added the output's screenshot to your answer.
Thanks for the answer. It is very helpful and taught me some new ways to work in R.
It got most things right. Proportions are incorrect though.  Proportion of As in the original Data is what is reqd. 3/10 = 0.3, B >> 2/10 = 0.2, C >> 5/10 = 0.5, D >> 0/10 = 0
And count for D is shown as 1.

Comment: @gyaan.anveyshak OK. I changed the count to just look at non-missing values.

Comment: Perfect!
If you would, please explain how "Value" is being defined / chosen within the summarize() function.